# multicraft ubuntu filezilla uploading files half of them corrupt

Tags: ubuntu, filezilla

[image]

As you can see by the zeros, the filesize is zero. How do I troubleshoot this problem? The files often get stuck being uploaded, and when they finish, the file size is zero. What causes this? connectivity issues? I tried rebooting the ubuntu server, restarting the multicraft instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things to check. I once had a similar issue uploading files to a server.

1. It appeared that the storage limited provided to me as a user had been exceeded. I was running a registrations portal on it and the users would upload a picture of themselves, which is primarily what drained my storage.
2. Sometimes the FTP is configured such that you can only upload a certain megabytes in one go. I have also faced issues due to that. Either increase that limit, or upload lesser files at a time.

(1) seems to be the more probable cause here. Try changing the user account to know for sure.